# xammp Vhosts in windows 10 is not working

Tags: php, apache, windows-10, vhosts

I have win 10 and i have installed xammp and i want to setup a virtual host

i have hosts file edited like that

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       unii
```

and i have the httpd-vhosts.conf like that

```
Listen 80 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/unii/public"
ServerName "unii"
</VirtualHost>
```

the Vhost redirect to the root of htdoc act like "localhost"

what is missed ??

Comment: Do you have directory, can be in vhosts or in conf? something like `<Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs/unii/publi">
        AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
     </Directory>` AllowOveride All on it's own line and also Require all granted on it's own line.

Comment: Try this remedy and then let me know

**httpd-vhosts.cnf**
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin me@localhost.com
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/unii/public"
   ServerName unii.localhost
</VirtualHost>

**In hosts file**
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 unii.localhost

Comment: Also check that `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` isn't commented out, in **conf**.

Comment: thanks @AshuJha now its working

Comment: thanks @MikeT for your response